# particle system is still rendered after deletion

Tags: rendering, particles, cache

so I made a particle emitter system only to delete it after, but this shot of the particle still rendered on the screen and when I render the image or the animation, I cant select them to delete them, any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: the server cannot upload files bigger than 30mb, mine is 45

Comment: You could try to reduce the size of the file by only leaving the necessary parts. Maybe in this process you find the culprit causing your issue.

Comment: thanks for guidance, i kept looking for a way to get into the project files, and kept deleting unused materials and meshes until i found the issue